# Subtract 3 months from datetime.now()

Tags: python

How do I remove 3 months from the date? tried to use `relativedelta`, but I don't have the lib, so is there another way?

```py
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
print("timestamp =", now)
```

Comment: And how is "remove 3 months" defined? That is not as easy as it looks at first...

Comment: Are your sure it's php code?

Comment: Sorry I'm used to do php code, but it's `python`! My Bad @KrisRoofe

Comment: I think this PHP tags why you put  python question here

Comment: @Hamza it's changed?

Comment: you need this code with php ?

Comment: @Hamza py, made a tag mistake

Comment: So, for example, what would 3 months before May 31st be?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille 28 feb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()

b = a - datetime.timedelta(weeks=12)
```

Note that you cannot give months as inputs, but weeks and days, and smaller

Comment: Note that for May 31st it would produce a date different than OP expected - March 8th as it internally changes weeks to days, i.e. `12 weeks = 12*7 days`. It would lead to a false conclusion that a year has 364 days, equally spread.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, subtracting with `datetime.timedelta` can help you estimate the date:

```py
import datetime
datetime.datetime(2019,5,31) - datetime.timedelta(3*365.25/12)
```

This result is not completely accurate, as it does not account for the leap years in the usual way, however for less precise calculations within a year should suffice. If you need accuracy you will need to use the method below.

For `dateutil.relativedelta`, you need to first install the module with `pip install python-dateutil`, and then use it in the following way:

```py
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
datetime.datetime(2019,5,31) - relativedelta(months=3)
```

Comment: relative delta is the best answer here

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform complex operations on datetime objects, I can only recommend you to use the library `arrow` that will handle all the edge cases for you.

The documentation of this library is available here: https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For instance in your case:

```py
>>> import arrow
>>> a = arrow.utcnow()
>>> a
<Arrow [2019-11-20T13:03:52.518238+00:00]>
>>> a.datetime
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 13, 3, 52, 518238, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> b = a.shift(months=-3)
>>> b
<Arrow [2019-08-20T13:03:52.518238+00:00]>
>>> b.datetime
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 20, 13, 3, 52, 518238, tzinfo=tzutc())
```